# Confused about two different definitions for the same object $\psi_i$ in the representation theory of $\mathrm{SU}(n)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let the entities $\psi^i$ transform as the fundamental representation of $\mathrm{SU}(n)$, denoted by ${\bf n}$:
$$
\psi^{\prime i}=U^{i}_{~j}\psi^j,
$$ where, of course, $U$ represents $n\times n$ unitary matrices with unit determinant. Taking complex conjugates on both sides, we get, $$
\left(\psi^{\prime i}\right)^{*}=\left(U^{i}_{~j}\right)^{*}(\psi^j)^{*}.
$$
Introducing the notation
$$
\psi_i=\left(\psi^i\right)^{*}, \quad U_{i}^{~j}=\left(U^{i}_{~j}\right)^{*},\tag{1}
$$
we have
$$
\psi^\prime_i=U_{i}^{~j}\psi_j.
$$
Therefore, by definition, $\psi_i=(\psi^i)^{*}$, which transform as $\bar{\bf n}$.

---

On the other hand, if I am not wrong, for the group $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, $\psi_i$ is **also** defined to be equal to $$\psi_i=\varepsilon_{ij}\psi^j.\tag{2}$$

How can we have two different definitions [in (1) and in (2)] for the same object $\psi_i$?

Answer (score 1):

OP's question is closely related to the fact that

- the [fundamental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_representation)/defining [representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation) $$\rho={\rm id}:SU(n)\to SU(n)\tag{1}$$
- and its [dual/contragredient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_representation)/transposed representation$^1$
  $$g~~\mapsto~~ (\rho(g)^{-1})^T,\qquad g~\in~SU(n), \tag{2}$$

are [inequivalent representations](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=equivalent+representations), except for $n=2$ due to the existence of the invariant 2D [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) $\epsilon$, cf. the following identity
$$(\rho(g)^{-1})^T~=~\epsilon \rho(g)\epsilon^{-1},\qquad g~\in~SU(2).\tag{3}$$

--

$^1$Note that the dual/contragredient/transposed representation (2) is equivalent to the [complex conjugate representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_representation) $\bar{\rho}$ due to unitarity.

Comment: Right. But my problem is somewhat more basic. It is true that for SU(2) group, $(\psi^i)^*=\varepsilon_{ij}\psi^j$. I don't think this is true because $\varepsilon_{ij}$ is just a real antisymmetric matrix and I am making a  mistake.

Comment: Can you expand a bit more on the connections? I'm familiar with all the linked concepts, but I don't see the implications between them. Maybe the core claim is that the fundamental representation and its complex conjugate are generically not (and should not be expected to be) equivalent, but that SU(2) is an exception? If so, how does the Levi-Civita work in connecting the two?

Comment: I updated the answer.